# What is the purpose of the holograms in Prometheus?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus, hologram

What is the purpose of the holograms in *Prometheus* that show what the Engineers did 2000 years ago? (Apart from the fact that they were used as a story telling tool)

Was there any reason in or out of universe for having this on board the Engineers' ship?

Comment: I imagine it's either a captain's log, or a security feed.

Comment: Sorry, clarification here- which holograms are we talking about? The navigation ones or the ones with the guys running or all of the above?

Comment: @Broklynite, all of them.

Comment: Second, the security log idea.  That would be the only logical explanation unless someone survived and created the logs deliberately. Which would kind of a strange act.

Comment: Note that David Keyed a sequence on that keypad that seemed to kick off the Holograms Lending Credence to the idea of a Captain's Log

Comment: i like the idea that the ship which i have read is a living being is explaining in the best way it can to creatures whose language it does not know what happened. the ship may be inherently compassionate and wants to warn the humans who it sees as kindred lifeforms.